# How to pass users back and forth using session data?

Tags: login, authentication, session

I have applications that I wrote that use SAML and then a user database to define permissions for them all.  And basically once a user signs on via our SSO they can use the applications with their defined perms.

I want to do the same thing for WP.  Where do I start?  I would like WP to recognize their session username before they login and then create wordpress cookie.  I saw a root cookie plugin that would pass the user info to other wp sites but how about getting the session username to begin with?

I would like users to come to WP site and see that they are logged in with their username but I am open for other ways too.

Right now what is given to me for SAML authentication is:

- app url: redirect to the SSO sign in
- app key: hash to encrypt
- uid
- firstname
- lastname
- email
- time (POST time is used for validation)

**Note:**  I have just tried using the SAML2 plugin for WP.  First it is a beta plugin and very confusing.  Second I keep getting fatal error that it cannot find IDP information.

Would really just like to take the session uid I have an log a person in using that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried any plugins, like [SAML 2.0 SSO](http://wordpress.org/plugins/saml-20-single-sign-on/)?

Comment: @MatthewBoynes - I tried out an earlier version of that plugin maybe a year ago.  Right now I am basically given an app url with an app key and a few fields and told to have fun (3rd party does our company's SSO).  So on my custom apps I simply verify that they have a session uid sent from the SSO (redirects to the app url if they dont).  Then I automatically authenticate based on the session uid on a user table that I maintain.  This might not be the most secure way but it works because it is all internal users.  I want the same session id to be WP username and log them in - no pass.

Comment: So you already have the users synced to wordpress and present in wp_users or what? Or where are the permissions coming from so Wordpress knows what the user is able to do?

Comment: @s1lv3r   I do a join with LDAP data and wp_users perm fields to make my own wp_users table.  The wp_users table works fine.  In a test environment I just took out the password authentication and when I login stating a uid I get the right perms per user.   The problem is how do I ensure that the uid is correct or keep someone from typing in whatever they want.

Comment: `The problem is how do I ensure that the uid is correct`. As far as I understand that is the part where SAML comes in. I.e you have a local service provider which checks this information against the IdP. If you don't get the SAML SSO plugin working you can also try to do this yourself with http://simplesamlphp.org/.

Comment: @s1lv3r - If it really were simple then there would be a simple SAML plugin that works.  I however do not need the full SAML functionality.  I already have a redirect working that takes them to SSO sign-in page and we get their uid in POST.   I just don't understand enough about the WP login (I usually make my own apps) to figure out what I need to do to pass the session uid to the wp login function.

Comment: If you already have the user-id and are sure everything is save the only thing you would need to do is to trigger http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie right?

Comment: Thanks for the link @s1lv3r.  Will see what happens when I tell wp authentication that $user_id is $POST['uid'] and that no password is needed.

Comment: $user_id just has to be a valid user from the wp_users table. Then wordpress will simply log that user in via setting the session cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a really simple script that is linked https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/154802/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-fully-integrate-a-custom-session-login-into-wp.

Basically I am assuming that your SSO is secure, that you have the users in your database, and that you don't need to keep the session alive except for authentication.  From my standpoint I just want to pass the user onto WP and let the WP user system do the rest.  Hope this helps others doing session logins.

Answer (score 2):

If you will work with sessions, then init this at first in your plugin, theme.

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_start_session' );

function my_start_session() {

    if ( session_id() )
        return;

    @session_cache_limiter('private, must-revalidate'); //private_no_expire
    @session_cache_expire(0);
    @session_start();
}
```

Alternative use the library from Eric Mann: [WP Session Manager](https://github.com/ericmann/wp-session-manager), also his [tutorial](http://eamann.com/tech/introducing-wp_session/).